# How to correctly name a class that contains property that returns value selected from sources set in this class and sets source values thes same way?

Tags: class, naming-conventions, naming, names, class-names

I've got a class that contains multiple potential sources of value (of same Type ofc) and property that returns value of some source based on provided sources (in order of importance, including internal value). I'd simply call it Provider, but property can be set also (and this actually sets some source value based on the same logic), so it looks incorrect.

I'd rather call it Two-Way Provider or Contractor (which is cumbersome), but it feels like I've got some pattern here, that has a specific or comprehensive name. More of "near-the-truth" variants: Dispenser, Conductor, Supply, Agent, Contributor. Something as simple as Node, but more specific.

tl;dr: Name must reflect all or most of these statements:

- class contains multiple external value sources that can be set "outside" (Exposer???)
- class contains "default" internal value (that can be "overriden" by source values) (Container?)
- class (property) always provide some value (Provider?)
- that (class's) property can be set (Receiver?)
- that value, which can be get or set, comes either from external value source (if any), either from internal value (Resolver?)
- looks logical next to the Type of value that class (property) presents (example: FloatProvider)

  ```
  public class FloatProvider //Needs proper name
  {
      public float internalValue = 1.0f; // these may be renamed
      public Foo fooSource = null;      // to make more sense
      public Bar barSource = null;      // in terms of the class

      public float Value
      {
          get => GetValue();
          set => SetValue(value);
      }

      public float GetValue()
      {
          if (fooSource!=null) return fooSource.value;
          else if (barSource!=null) return barSource.value;
          else return internalValue;
      }

      public void SetValue(float value)
      {
          if (fooSource!=null) fooSource.value = value;
          else if (barSource!=null) barSource.value = value;
          else internalValue = value;
      }

      public FloatProvider(float internalValue, Foo fooSource, Bar barSource)
      {
          this.internalValue = internalValue;
          this.fooSource = fooSource;
          this.barSource = barSource;
      }
  }

  public class Foo
  {
      public float value = 10.0f;
  }

  public class Bar
  {
       public float value = 0.1f;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

After days of head scratching and eventual epiphanies I think the **Hub** is the most appropriate term. But in my case I'd rather call the class by its purpose (FloatExt or something).